# Boolean operator OR in where clause using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Hello folks,
            I am trying to set a fixed value to a tag in XML on comparing to a value in condition. such as

```
<xsl:when test="(//TestInput='XYZA') OR (//TestInput='XYZB') OR (//TestInput='XYZC') OR (//TestInput='XYZD')">abcd</xsl:when>
```

when i trying to run the transformation with an XML with tag `<TestInput>`, it is giving me an error as

```
Extra illegal tokens: '(', '/', '/', 'TestInput', '=', ''XYZA'', ')', 'OR', '(', '/', '/', 'TestInput', '=', ''XYZB'', ')', 'OR', '(', '/', '/', 'TestInput', '=', ''XYZC'', ')', 'OR', '(', '/', '/', 'TestInput', '=', ''XYZD'', ')'
```

Please help me out in setting the value to this tag based on condition using OR operator in where clause.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What platform/parser are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Case matters with XML/XSLT/XPath so use `or` instead of `OR`.

Comment: As an additional note, with XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can simplify such a comparison to `//TestInput = ('foo', 'bar', 'foobar')`. That is however not possible with XSLT/XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

I created a test with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
  <Item>DAC</Item>
  <Item>DAD</Item>
  <Item>DAE</Item>
</Test>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <test>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//Item[text()='DAC'] or //Item[text()='DAE']">
          <output>Here is the text!</output>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      </test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <output>Here is the text!</output>
</test>
```

Tested with Micorosft.Net's XmlDocument class. The critical difference is the **case** of the '*or*' statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that //TestInput selects a set of elements instead of just one.

You should use xsl:for-each

```
<xsl:for-each select="//TestInput[.='a'or'b'or'c']">abc</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `//TestInput[.='a'or'b'or'c']` is incorrect XPath. It evaluates as `//TestInput[.='a'or true() or true()]` and hence is always `true` in the end. You must do actual comparsions.